# R loops with matrix and vectors: better (faster) solutions?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, vector

I wrote some function to fill an empty matrix with relevant datapoints which I select from a dataset. 
The function works, but as the size of the dataset increases (the full dataset has about 100k rows) it becomes way to slow because I use to many loops. 
If anyone has any tips on how to do this more effectively I would appreciate it. I already implemented the `table()[]` function and tried a lot of other things out of the apply family, but this is the best I could do.

Lets say the dataset looks like this:

```
data<-structure(c("concentration permitted by column 3", "concentration permitted under the national", 
            "concentration phenomena  nonlinear dynamics", "concentration phosphorus concentrations phosphorus load", 
            "concentration plan in greek language", "concentration plan in political science", 
            "58", "104", "43", "114", "102", "58"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
              c("", "", "", "", "", ""), NULL))
```

And lets assume the matrix looks like this:

```
mat<-structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 
                                                                          4L), .Dimnames = list(c("phosphorus", "interest", "concentration", "phenomena"
                                                                          ), c("phosphorus", "interest", "concentration", "phenomena")))
```

If the words contained in the rownames + columnames of, lets say `mat[1,3]`, occur together in data[,1], I want to save the corresponding counts from `data[,2]` to `mat[1,3]`.
In other words, "phosphorus" and "concentration" occur together in the dataset `(data[4,])` and have a count of "114", `data[4,2]`. This value should be written to `mat[1,3].`

Thus, want I want is this:

```
      mat
              phosphorus interest concentration phenomena
phosphorus           114        0           114         0
interest               0        0             0         0
concentration        114        0           479        43
phenomena              0        0            43        43
```

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
data_words<-list()
length(data_words)<-nrow(data)


for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data_words[[i]]<-unlist(regmatches(data[i,1],gregexpr("(\\S+)",data[i,1],perl=TRUE)))
}

for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(mat)){
    for(k in seq_along(data_words)){

      if( sum(table(rownames(mat)[i])[data_words[[k]]],na.rm = T)>0 & 
            sum(table(colnames(mat)[j])[data_words[[k]]],na.rm = T)>0){
        mat[i,j]<-as.numeric(mat[i,j])+as.numeric(data[k,2])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice question. You might not want to label an object as `matrix`, since that is also the name of a function.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y <- sapply(colnames(mat), function(x) grepl(x,data[,1]))
z <- expand.grid(seq_along(colnames(mat)),seq_along(colnames(mat)))
x <- matrix(0,dim(z)[1],length(colnames(mat)))
x[cbind(seq_along(z[,1]),z[,1])] <- 1
x[cbind(seq_along(z[,1]),z[,2])] <- x[cbind(seq_along(z[,1]),z[,2])] + 1 
mat[as.matrix(z)] <- (x %*% t(y) > 1) %*% as.numeric(data[,2])

> mat
              phosphorus interest concentration phenomena
phosphorus           114        0           114         0
interest               0        0             0         0
concentration        114        0           479        43
phenomena              0        0            43        43
```

Comment: This indeed is a much better solution to the problem. Thank you very much for your help.